# Visual Studio c# Key press enter not working

Tags: c#, winforms, keypress

Hey guys I've been struggling with my code ! I did some research and I don't understand why my code isn't working... Please help !

```
private void CheckEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("It's working!");
            enterKey = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enterKey = false;
        }
    }

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("The text is changing");

        if (enterKey == true)
        {
            encryptKey = encryptInTextBox.Text;
            Debug.WriteLine("The key is " + encryptKey);
        }
    }
```

Apparently I can't change 'TextChangedEvenArgs' because of how the text box was created, whenever I change it, it comes with an error.
So, I decided to do it this way, thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you check the ENTER key directly into the textbox KEYPRESS or KEYUP event?

Comment: Yes, but I would have to change the "TextChangedEvenArgs" to "System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs" right ?

Comment: Yes. You can select the KeyPress or KeyUp event in the top of your editor, in the "Method" combobox. Put you mouse within the TextChanged event and see aboce that you can set the KeyPress/KeyUp events.  And put your char(13) critic within that event. I mean, both events you utilize now will be in one single.

Comment: Thanks ! "It's working!" ;P I ran through little problems but then figure it out, thanks again !